# IBM Worklight - Error while validating project during deployment

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I have created an application using IBM worklight and i am using customAuthenticator for login process

I am getting following validation error while deploying application

> Security test DummyAdapter-securityTest must include user and device
>   realms for AuthDemo:iphone:1.0:api. [project
>   module_23_1_CustomLoginModule]

Comment: You need to add more information on what you are doing, how your setup is, and also add some code where relevant. The [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) page is a really good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-read the entire Getting Started [section about Authentication and Security](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#security). There is more reading material [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/dev/c_ibm_worklight_security_overview.html) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding_predefined_worklight_authentication_realms_and_security_tests11?lang=en).

From the error I am thinking you have added a `securityTest="DummyAdapter-securityTest"` attribute to your `iphone` element in `application-descriptor.xml`.

As noted by the name of the `securityTest`, it is not meant for the application but for the adapter. This securityTest is already defined for the adapter procedure in the adapter XML file. Remove the securityTest you've added and it will work.

---

The sample you are trying to run (module_23_1_CustomLoginModule) is ready-made; no need for editing. You need only to build & deploy and run it.

Comment: If I removed securityTest then how can I define customSecurity for my application ?

Comment: Did you read the training modules...? Please read them first.