# To call the adapter is there a way to set it or bypass in web browser? I mean to bypass wl_antiXSRFRealm when I try to hit in browser?

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter, mobilefirst-adapters, custom-authentication

I created a simple custom login module for mobilefirst java adapter.

authentication-config.xml

```
<customSecurityTest name="DummyAdapter-securityTest" AccessTokenExpirationSec="15">
<test isInternalUserID="true" realm="CustomAuthenticatorRealm"/></customSecurityTest> 

<realm name="CustomAuthenticatorRealm" loginModule="CustomerLoginModule">           <className>com.mbanking.customauthenticator.CustomerAuthenticator</className>
</realm>

<loginModule name="CustomerLoginModule">            <className>com.mbanking.customauthenticator.CustomerLoginModule</className>
</loginModule>
```

Defined the following in application-descriptor.xml

```
<userIdentityRealms>CustomAuthenticatorRealm</userIdentityRealms>
```

I am authenticating a hard coded username and password in the CustomerAuthenticator and CustomerLoginModule as given in the IBM tutorials.

```
    @Override
    public AuthenticationResult processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            boolean isAccessToProtectedResource) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (request.getRequestURI() != null){

         String username = "Prabhu";
         String password = "polo11";

if (null != username && null != password && username.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0){
                authenticationData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                authenticationData.put("username", username);
                authenticationData.put("password", password);
                return AuthenticationResult.createFrom(AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS);
            } else {
                response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
                response.getWriter().print("{\"authStatus\":\"required\", \"errorMessage\":\"Please enter username and password\"}");
                return AuthenticationResult.createFrom(AuthenticationStatus.CLIENT_INTERACTION_REQUIRED);
            }
        }

        if (!isAccessToProtectedResource){
            return AuthenticationResult.createFrom(AuthenticationStatus.REQUEST_NOT_RECOGNIZED);
        } 
        response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
        response.getWriter().print("{\"authStatus\":\"required\"}");
        return AuthenticationResult.createFrom(AuthenticationStatus.CLIENT_INTERACTION_REQUIRED);
}
```

Login Module

```
@Override
    public boolean login(Map<String, Object> authenticationData) {
          USERNAME =(String) authenticationData.get("username");
          PASSWORD = (String) authenticationData.get("password");

          if ("Prabhu".equals(USERNAME) && "polo11".equals(PASSWORD)){
          return true;
          }else{
              throw new RuntimeException("Invalid credentials"); 
              } 
    }
```

Java Adapter code

```
@GET
    @Path("/mobile")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @OAuthSecurity(scope="CustomAuthenticatorRealm")
    public JSONObject generate(){
        JSONObject responseValue = new JSONObject();
        responseValue.put("data", "Secret Data From Adpter");       
        return responseValue;   
    }
```

Authorization is failing

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0059E: Login into realm 'CustomerLoginModule' failed. null. [project JIB]
java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0117E: Error code: 4, error description: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, error message: An error occurred while performing authentication using loginModule CustomerLoginModule, User Identity {wl_antiXSRFRealm=(name:lbgo1f8edsjvsjgfv8i9umdneb, loginModule:WLAntiXSRFLoginModule), wl_authenticityRealm=null, CustomAuthenticatorRealm=(name:Prabhu, loginModule:CustomerLoginModule), CustomRealm=null, wl_directUpdateRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=null, SampleAppRealm=null, myserver=(name:ac09d1e7-71a6-47da-bbb8-e6c2f48651f3, loginModule:WeakDummy), wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_anonymousUserRealm=(name:ac09d1e7-71a6-47da-bbb8-e6c2f48651f3, loginModule:WeakDummy), wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null}. [project JIB] [project JIB]
```

and When I tried debugging, I get internal exception.

```
CLIENT_INTERACTION_REQUIRED{"challenges":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"lr0tsjecoeghhrf670oc8hu17v"}}}
```

There is lot of caching, even after restarting, mobile first server is picking up old values.

Can anyone please help?
Its a one way authorization, why wl_antiXSRFRealm is called in between, I dont get any references related to this.

Comment: Did you apply your custom security test also on the environment? i.e. in application-descriptor.xml did you set something like: `<android securityTest="yourcustomsecuritytest"/>`?

Comment: No I didnt add anything with respect to environment. I created a form submit in index.html and writing 

'var request = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/AuthCodeGenerator/API/mobile", WLResourceRequest.GET);'

in main.js

Comment: Unless you specify the security test in the application-descriptor.xml in the environment (as mentioned above), you will get the antiXSRF test by default

Comment: Thank you, I will check configuring environment for the same.

Comment: I have added the following in my app-descriptor.xml '<userIdentityRealms>CustomAuthenticatorRealm</userIdentityRealms>' and I am not doing adding any customdeviceprovisioning

Comment: Again, you are getting the wl_antiXSRF failure because every environment is protected by default by security tests. Because you did not specify any security test on the environment, it is thus protected by the default ones: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding_predefined_worklight_authentication_realms_and_security_tests11?lang=en

Comment: [ERROR   ] FWLSE0335E: Authorization failed: ClientId BW7hQ1l6s9 was not found on the server. I get this error as well. So it means that I am not sneding it from client request. Thank you once again.

Comment: After adding in app-descriptor I get the error as in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704833/ibm-worklight-error-while-validating-project-during-deployment)

Comment: I see. Then you need to protect your adapter procedure instead. See what is written in that other link.

Comment: Yes I am trying to protect the adapter. Thanks. I removed the definitions and now I get 'CLIENT_INTERACTION_REQUIRED{"challenges":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"98u2bnt47h58a04ioeuh8jfibh"},"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"token":"5fpqo2h1e2gmsv9s9k0tq9js1v"}}}' in android simulator in the browser I could see Response 222 undefined.

Comment: I got the security test with respect to mobile & web. To call the adapter is there a way to set it or bypass in web browser? I mean to bypass wl_antiXSRFRealm when I try to hit in browser?